# calling gui function in a non-gui m file - Matlab

Tags: matlab

So I have been trying to call a button callback function in `test_gui.m` function in non-gui m file say `test2.m`.

But I fail all the time. I tried using `findall` or `findobj` but still I get a problem. could you tell me if there is anything I have to do?

Comment: What is the error displayed on the command window ? By default, you have arguments for GUI callback which are the handle and eventdata. Can you show your callback function ?

Comment: @oro777 reference to no existing field, that is what i get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access any functions in an m file except for the function by which the file is named.

For example, you have an m file named func.m which contains functions func(), helper_func1(), and helper_func2(); only func() will be available to any code outside of that file.  See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html: "Local functions are only available to other functions within the same file."

What you want is to create a new file named helper_func1.m containing helper_func1() and then call that function from test2.m as well as inside test_gui.m.